# Reusing Flyway Migrations between SpringBoot Tests (Zonky + Flyway + SpringBoot3)

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I've been using Zonky Embedded DB Spring Tests + Flyway Spring Test to do integration testing with in-memory databases built from a collection of SQL migration scripts managed by Flyway.  The issue I'm having is that, as of SpringBoot 3, this configuration is resulting in the Flyway Migrations being reapplied between any tests that alter the SpringBoot Context.  The DB container itself isn't restarted, but the migrations are reapplied.  This is both slowing down test execution and forcing me to re-write the migration scripts to be repeatable.

In SpringBoot 2, this was not the case.  The embedded test DB would be refreshed between tests, but would not re-run migrations.

Is there a way to replicate the behavior from Zonky+Flyway from SpringBoot2, where the migrations would NOT be re-applied between each context dirtying test?

ex.

***application-test.yaml***

```
spring.flyway.mixed: true
spring.flyway.schemas: public,test
zonky.test.database.provider: zonky
zonky.test.database.refresh: never
```

***Example Tests***

```
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class DemoApplicationTests {
   
   @Test
   void contextLoads() {
   }
}
```

```
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class DemoApplicationTests2 {
   
   @Test
   void contextLoads() {
   }
}
```

```
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class DemoApplicationTests3 {
   @MockBean RestTemplate restTemplate; //Add a mock that requires the SpringBoot context to be re-created

   @Test
   void contextLoads() {
   }
}
```

Originally, when I was running this setup in SpringBoot 2, the DB migrations would be run once, while initializing the context for executing DemoApplicationTests1.  The DB would then be re-used for Test 2 and 3, even though Test3 would re-initialize the SpringBoot Context due to the additional mock.

***SpringBoot 2 libraries***

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.6'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
...
testImplementation 'io.zonky.test:embedded-database-spring-test:2.1.1'
testImplementation 'io.zonky.test:embedded-postgres:1.3.1'
testImplementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.3.0'
testImplementation 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions:flyway-spring-test:7.0.0'
testImplementation enforcedPlatform('io.zonky.test.postgres:embedded-postgres-binaries-bom:12.10.0')
```

After updating to SpringBoot3, and migrating to newer, compatible versions of the zonky and flyway libraries, this is behaving differently.  The embedded DB is re-used between Tests 1 and 2, but during the Spring context re-initialization for Test 3, the Flyway migrations are being re-run.

***SpringBoot 3 libraries***

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
...
testImplementation 'io.zonky.test:embedded-database-spring-test:2.2.0'
testImplementation 'io.zonky.test:embedded-postgres:2.0.3'
testImplementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:9.15.2'
testImplementation 'org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions:flyway-spring-test:7.0.0'
testImplementation enforcedPlatform('io.zonky.test.postgres:embedded-postgres-binaries-bom:12.10.0')
```

***Logs from Test3***

```
2023-04-03T11:01:14.557-05:00  INFO 31396 --- [  prefetching-2] o.f.c.i.database.base.BaseDatabaseType   : Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:53919/hzukrkxcbfcz (PostgreSQL 12.10)
2023-04-03T11:01:14.618-05:00  INFO 31396 --- [  prefetching-2] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 5 migrations (execution time 00:00.019s)
2023-04-03T11:01:14.619-05:00  INFO 31396 --- [  prefetching-2] o.f.core.internal.database.base.Schema   : Creating schema "test" ...
2023-04-03T11:01:14.630-05:00  INFO 31396 --- [  prefetching-2] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history" ...
2023-04-03T11:01:14.875-05:00  INFO 31396 --- [  prefetching-2] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": null
2023-04-03T11:01:14.893-05:00  INFO 31396 --- [  prefetching-2] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "public" to version "0 - init"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Flyway 9.15.2 wasn't supported at that moment. Try to upgrade to embedded-database-spring-test:2.5.0 that should solve your problem. Next time, feel free to open an issue directly on [the GitHub page](https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-database-spring-test/issues) of the project.